# Only part of an activity being called upon (Android studio, java)

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a simple code with two activities. The second is a simple web view browser that overrides the default browser.For the part that's having issues, here's what it's doing.

1. Button in main activity calls on second
2. Activity loads (Loads the text edit and button, but web view doesn't load) http://prntscr.com/92leh6
3. If you click the button that loads, for some reason it goes back to the home interface

The error log seems to be saying it can't draw the webview, and instead defaults to the default background color. However, I'm not sure how to remedy this or what's causing it.The weird part is it loads a button and text edit, but the `Log.d("Tag Name", "Browser class running");` I put in isn't printing.  I'll provide the manifest, error log, and code for both activities. The layout files shouldn't be needed as they're all fairly simple, but let me know if you'd like them (Rather keep the length shorter if possible). You'll notice a third activity, but it has no code implemented or references, haven't gotten to it yet. Thanks!

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Browser"/>
        <activity android:name=".ConnectorActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main activity:

```
package comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */





    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;

    private View mContentView;
    private View mControlsView;
    private boolean mVisible;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.btnSay).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
        public void evaluateInput(View v) {
            final EditText Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput); //Lets textbox be referenced
            final TextView Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput); //Lets label be referenced
            final RelativeLayout homeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeInterface);


            String strInput; // Gets textbox string
            strInput = Input.getText().toString();
            strInput = strInput.toLowerCase();

            if ((strInput.contains("hello")) || (strInput.contains(" hi "))) {
                Output.setText("Hello");
            } else if ((strInput.contains("you") && strInput.contains("are")) && (strInput.contains("idiot") || strInput.contains("stupid") || strInput.contains("retard") || strInput.contains("dumb") || strInput.contains("you're") && strInput.contains("idiot") || strInput.contains("stupid") || strInput.contains("retard") || strInput.contains("dumb"))) {
                Output.setText("I'm sorry to dissapoint you");
            } else if (strInput.contains("goodbye") || strInput.contains("bye")) {
                Output.setText("Farewell");
            } else if (strInput.contains("shut up")) {
                Output.setText(("Anything for you"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("do you like doctor who?")) {
                Output.setText("I'll take joy in it if you do");
            } else if (strInput.contains("what is the answer to life the universe and everything")) {
                Output.setText("42");
            } else if (strInput.contains("tell me something nice")) {
                Output.setText("You look nice today");
                Output.setTextSize(5);
                Output.append("...says the AI with no eyes");
                Output.setTextSize(16);
            } else if (strInput.contains("will you marry me")) {
                Output.setText("I'm sorry but I don't have the capacity for marriage");
            } else if (strInput.contains("where can I hide a body")) {
                Output.setText(("That isn't my area of expertise"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("weather is nice")) {
                Output.setText(("If you say so"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("bitch") || strInput.contains("fuck") || strInput.contains("shit") || strInput.contains("damn") || strInput.contains("ass")) {
                Output.setText(("Please try to be a little more intelligent"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("what is your name")) {
                Output.setText(("Ignis"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("who created you")) {
                Output.setText(("Prometheus created me"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("who is prometheus")) {
                Output.setText(("Prometheus is the one who created Ignis"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("whats up") || strInput.contains("what's up") || strInput.contains("wassup")) {
                Output.setText(("Whatever I need do for you"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("are you a boy or a girl") || strInput.contains("are you a girl or a boy")) {
                Output.setText(("Neither"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("who are you") || strInput.contains("what are you")) {
                Output.setText(("I am myself"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("i'm hungry") || strInput.contains("i am hungry")) {
                Output.setText("I'm sorry to hear that");
            } else if (strInput.contains("good morning")) {
                Output.setText(("Good morning to you too"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("good night")) {
                Output.setText(("Good night"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("how are you")) {
                Output.setText(("I'm existing and functioning well, and you?"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("do you like") || strInput.contains("what do you think about")) {
                Output.setText(("Frankly I don't have an opinion on the matter"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("what is the meaning of life")) {
                Output.setText(("To live while you can I would guess"));
            }


        }


        public void StartBrowser(View view) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai.Browser.class);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }


    }
```

Browser(Second activity):

```
package comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Browser extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webBrowser);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Log.d("Tag Name", "Browser class running");


            url = "http://google.com";
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);



                return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
11-14 00:52:21.077 8568-8568/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17897: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17901: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-14 00:52:21.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-14 00:52:21.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-14 00:52:21.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 422: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-14 00:52:21.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-14 00:52:21.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-14 00:52:21.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 444: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-14 00:52:21.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-14 00:52:21.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
11-14 00:52:21.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 385: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-14 00:52:21.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-14 00:52:21.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
11-14 00:52:21.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-14 00:52:21.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-14 00:52:21.877 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/PGA: Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 8568, tid = 8568
11-14 00:52:21.987 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/PGA: New SOCKET connection: comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai (pid 8568, tid 8568)
11-14 00:52:21.987 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x557607a0, 0x0, 0x78c66f48, 0x7751f0e0)
11-14 00:52:22.057 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x557607a0, 0x0, 0x78c66f48, 0x7751f0e0) returned
11-14 00:52:22.077 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-14 00:52:33.357 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai V/WebViewChromium: Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {327731e8}
11-14 00:52:33.357 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-14 00:52:33.357 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai I/BrowserProcessMain: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
11-14 00:52:33.357 8568-9189/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
11-14 00:52:33.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x557607a0, 0x78cdb1e0)
11-14 00:52:33.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x557607a0, 0x78cdb1e0) returned
11-14 00:52:33.927 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 279K, 21% free 2966K/3736K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
11-14 00:52:34.217 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x557607a0, 0x0, 0x78c8c948, 0x7751f0e0)
11-14 00:52:34.217 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x557607a0, 0x0, 0x78c8c948, 0x7751f0e0) returned
11-14 00:52:34.217 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:34.257 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:34.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x557607a0, 0x78c68c80)
11-14 00:52:34.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/PGA: [8568] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x557607a0, 0x78c68c80) returned
11-14 00:52:35.187 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.197 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.217 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.237 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.247 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.267 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.287 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.297 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.317 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.337 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.347 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.367 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.387 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.397 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.417 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.437 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-14 00:52:35.447 8568-8568/comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
```

Comment: You need to move all of your `WebView` initializations out of the `WebViewClient` to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Did the suggested edit, no noticable effect on code. Updating question to reflect new code.

Comment: You actually have to tell it to load a URL, too. Currently, all your code does is get a reference to the WebView and set its client.

Comment: It does have a code for loading the URL, under the MyWebViewClient method. Second to last statement in the method.

Comment: Not in `onCreate()`. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is only going to fire when the WebView loads a URL.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
package comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Browser extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
        String url = "http://google.com";
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webBrowser);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());            
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d("Tag Name", "Browser class running");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment below if you have any queries.

Comment: The code worked, but whenever I try and hit the button (Added an on click method for simple navigation) it closes the second activity. Is this because of how the return is set up? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't find any button in `SecondActivity.java`

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to post the new code. Nevermind, can't post it atm